# Can't reset git credentials

Tags: git, github

I would like to push code to a repo to user1 account on github but when I run `git push -u origin main`  I get the following error

```
Username for 'https://github.com': user1
Password for 'https://user1@github.com': 
remote: Permission to user1/<reponame>.git denied to user2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user1/<reponame>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I tried setting the credentials locally and globally with

```
git config --global user.name "user1"
git config --global user.email "user1@gmail.com"


git config --local user.name "user1"
git config --local user.email "user1@gmail.com"
```

everything works fine until I run the git push command mentioned above I enter my username and password but i still get this error

even tried this

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

but still the same error

How to remove the credentials of other users

I am running kali linux and I user multiple github accounts for different projects

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?  Does the error literally say `<reponame>`, or have you edited that for the sake of the question?

Comment: ```git remote -v ``` shows the remote repo with the name I used all seems right 

```origin  https://github.com/user1/reponame.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user1/reponame.git (push) ```

Comment: The `user.name` and `user.email` settings *are not used to authenticate* (they are there for Git to put into new commits only, not for any other purpose). HTTPS authentication on GitHub is done by GitHub, using the user name you provide and a personal access token (passwords are no longer used for this at GitHub). See https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Note that you may use ssh *instead of* HTTPS to connect to GitHub; in this case, the authentication system is entirely different, as it uses ssh keys. You can use different keys to authenticate under different user names.

Comment: Git does not have "credentials". This really is not a Git question at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the `.git/config` file by using:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/repo-name.git
```

Comment: does not work and when you create a new repo in the browser this is the same command provided by github and i tried it but still got the user2 error

Answer (score 0):

The Git FAQ explains how to do this both [for HTTPS](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-http) and [for SSH](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-http).

Note that if you do so, you can't use the clone URL that you copy directly from the GitHub web interface because it will need to be modified to either include a username or different hostname (for HTTPS and SSH, respectively).

You should also be aware that `user.name` is not a username and doesn't affect authentication in any way.  As [the Git FAQ explains about the intended contents](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-http):

> You should put your personal name, generally a form using a given name and family name. For example, the current maintainer of Git uses "Junio C Hamano". This will be the name portion that is stored in every commit you make.
>
> This configuration doesn’t have any effect on authenticating to remote services; for that, see `credential.username` in `git-config(1)`.